# Swagger-PHP multiple definitions ("views") for same model

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-php

I am using swagger-php to create a documentation for my REST API built with Yii2. Further I am using the Yii2 [scenario feature](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios), which means I can re-use the same model for multiple purposes. As can example, consider this minimal example for a user class:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Definition(definition="UserLogin", required={"username", "login_password"}, type="object", @SWG\Xml(name="UserLogin"))
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_LOGIN = 'login';
    const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';

    public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_LOGIN] = ['username', 'login_password'];
        $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_CREATE] = ['username', 'firstname'];
        return $scenarios;
    }

    /**
     * Password
     * @var string
     * @SWG\Property(example="secret_password")
     */
    public $login_password;

    /**
     * Password
     * @var string
     * @SWG\Property(example="admin")
     */
    public $username;

    /**
     * firstname
     * @var string
     * @SWG\Property(example="SomeName")
     */
    public $firstname;
}
```

The Swagger definition will now include all fields, but only `username` and `login_password` will be required. What I instead need are two different definitions matching the defined scenarios. In this example, this would be:

- Definition `UserLogin` including the fields `username` and `login_password`
- Definition `UserCreate` including the fields `username` and firstname`
- Definition `User` including all fields

How to achieve this using swagger-php?

Comment: There is a discussion about it on swagger-php github: https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/39 however it has not been implemented yet

Comment: Check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your answer and you can also use global fields like bellow.

```
/**
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *      definition="UserLogin",
 *      required={"username", "login_password"},
 *      type="object",
 *      @SWG\Xml(name="UserLogin"),
 *      @SWG\Property(type="string", property="username", description="User name"),
 *      @SWG\Property(type="string", property="login_password", description="Login password"),
 * ),
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *      definition="UserCreate",
 *      required={"username", "login_password"},
 *      type="object",
 *      @SWG\Xml(name="UserLogin"),
 *      @SWG\Property(type="string", property="username", description="User name"),
 *      @SWG\Property(type="string", property="firstname", description="First name"),
 * ),
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *      definition="User",
 *      required={"username", "login_password"},
 *      type="object",
 *      @SWG\Xml(name="UserLogin"),
 *      @SWG\Property(type="string", property="login_password", description="Login password"),
 *      @SWG\Property(type="string", property="username", description="User name"),
 *      @SWG\Property(type="string", property="firstname", description="First name"),
 *)
 */
```

Thanks,